# How long will vacuum sealed grilled lemons keep in the refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety

I have cut in half and grilled lemons, then marinated with sugar, herbs and a little oil... All of which have been vacuum sealed in my fridge for about two months.

Comment: Have you measured their actual pH before sealing?

Comment: No, I didn't measure the pH level

Answer (score 3):

Vacuum sealing food does not make it safe at all. You have to treat it like any other cooked food, only with the added risk of botulism.

I was looking into whether your lemons might be acidic enough to be treated as a refrigerator pickle. I could not however find anything to confirm that. Worse, newer studies recommend against previously used "tried and tested" refrigerator pickle recipes due to listeriosis danger.

So no, it is not safe. You shouldn't store it for longer than 5 days.